# Checkout from subversion using Jenkins locks my AD account

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am able to checkout files from Subversion in my VM using my Active Directory username and password. When I checkout the same files using Jenkins, it checks out the files but also locks my Active Directory username.

Jenkins is at version 1.520 and above; Subversion plugin is at version 1.43/1.45.

When I enter the repository URL in the job's **Source code management** section (path has no environment variables in it), initially it asks me to enter credentials. When I enter my username and password, the first time it says `Authentication successful` but from the second time onwards it throws a `FAILED: svn: E125002: Malformed URL ''` error.

My Active Directory security settings in the configuration of Jenkins also shows success for the entered domain name, Bind DN and password.

Subversion is installed on a remote VM which I have access to.

What is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that subversion had cached my password. So deleting .subversion from my home dir and recreating it solved the problem